# Convert UTC to different time zones without day light savings

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

Currently I have an UTC date which I have to convert to different time zone based on where my client time zone is.

This is the code am currently using:

```
var timezoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezone);
var clientTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(createDateTime, timezoneInfo);
```

I know this automatically uses the daylight saving time and provide me the current time based on time zone.
I have a boolean which determines whether is daylight saving time is enabled or not. The above method doesn't work well based on my boolean value.
Is there a inbuilt method or code that converts UTC to different time zone without daylight saving time?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a bad idea to provide a boolean daylight saving time flag in your application at all.  Time zones are all about the actual local time in a particular area, and that *always* includes whether the government that controls that time zone has decided if daylight saving time applies or not.  In other words - it's not up to the user, it's up to their government.  Microsoft and the IANA time zone community go out of their way to ensure the time zones accurately reflect those governmental decisions.

If you really must do this, you could consider either using the `TimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset` property, or you could inspect the result of `TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime` to decide whether to subtract time from the result.  However, both approaches suffer from edge cases that will give you errors in cases where the *standard time* offset has changed unrelated to daylight saving time.  Additionally, not all time zones shift by a full hour for DST, there's one that shifts by 30 minutes.

Ultimately, my recommendation would be to keep your code as-is and *not* try to use that boolean flag.  Instead, go back to the UX or wherever that flag originates and remove it.

Comment: Incidentally, the "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" option in the Windows date/time settings page suffers from the same issues, which is why it is generally recommended to leave that *ON*.  There are only a few rare cases where it should be temporarily disabled.  Don't copy that pattern into your application - it was a mistake in Windows to begin with.

Comment: The reason i want to implement this change is bcoz one of the client is from Arizona and they set to Mountain time but with the boolean false, so wats happening is when we get a date in December the above inbuilt method includes the day light savings time but Arizona doesnt follow day light time and the time we get is totally wrong with a difference of one hour. So we will not be able to change the client time zone from Mountain time, tat field is unchangeable

Comment: There are two separate time zones for Mountain Time.  If you're running on Windows, the ID for Mountain Time with DST is `"Mountain Standard Time"` (display name is "(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)") and the ID for Mountain Time *without* DST (for Arizona) is `"US Mountain Standard Time"` (display name is "(UTC-07:00) Arizona")  (If on Linux or macOS, the IDs are `"America/Denver"` and `"America/Phoenix"` respectively.)  Use the correct time zone ID and there will be no need to adjust it manually.